# How I can open map with MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

First off, sorry for my english.
I have a problem :(
I want to open the map of the city.
I can use following construction:

```
NSString *opMap = [[NSString alloc]
initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=new+york+21st+street"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:opMap]];
[opMap release];
```

But, this - map opens up Safari. I want to open this address (for example New York 21st street(in reality - this address will be provided by a server) with MKMapView. 
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **geocoding** and **MKMapView**. http://files.mettigel-software.com/TSGeocoder.zip is a sample code from my bookmarks, it uses google services. But I am not sure if it violates google's TOS or not.

You should just geocode the address and than show latitude and longitude in **MKMapView**.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, geocoding - that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can open the google maps URL and read the returned HTML and find the string '\x26ll='.  What follows that is the lat/lon pair, comma separated.